# Add elements to webform dynamically via hook_form_alter

Tags: hooks, webforms

I'm trying to dynamically add multiple toggle fields to a form (in my case webform) via a form-alter-hook.

```
function module_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
....
  foreach ($roles as $role) {
    $form['elements'][$role->id()] = array(
      '#type' => 'webform_toggle',
      '#title' => t($role->label()),
      '#default_value' => 0,
      // More webform specific arguments follow here.
      '#webform_id' => "edit_membership_roles--" . $role->id(),
      '#webform_key' => $role->id(),
      '#webform_parent_key' => "",
      '#webform_parent_flexbox' => FALSE,
      '#webform_depth' => 0,
      '#webform_children' => [],
      '#webform_parents' => [$role->id()],
      '#webform_multiple' => FALSE,
      '#webform_composite' => FALSE,
      '#admin_title' => $role->id(),
      '#webform' => "edit_membership_roles",
      '#webform_submission' => NULL,
      '#access' => TRUE,
      '#webform_element' => TRUE,
      '#element_validate' => [],
    );
  }
}
```

This works in a way that the form is displayed correctly, with all dynamically added toggle elements. However, when trying to load the `WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission` via `$webform_submission->getData();` in my custom `class FormHandler extends WebformHandlerBase {...}`, the array only contains the elements that I manually added to the webform via the GUI.

I checked the first answer of this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22517/add-element-to-the-beginning-of-form-via-hook-form-alter), but my `$form` does not have a `$form['submitted']`

Am I just missing something or does this approach not work at all?

**Update**

I did the same approach with a custom form built with Drupal FormApi and it works. So I must be missing something specific to webforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding elements dynamically via hook form alter does not work because the Webform module can't recognize the new elements.  Your best bet is to create a custom webform element.

Answer (score 0):

In first instance I would also go with the suggested approach by @jrockowitz.

However I had a use case where the element was already in use and it couldn't be swapped out with a new element. What we ended up doing was to substitute the element's class with an extended class in a `.module` file:

```
use Drupal\foo\Plugin\WebformElement\CustomWebformToggle;

/**
 * Implements hook_webform_element_info_alter().
 */
function CUSTOM_MODULE_webform_element_info_alter(array &$definitions) {
  // Substitute the original element class with additional functionality.
  $definitions['webform_toggle']['class'] = CustomWebformToggle::class;
}
```

In the extended class I also had to implement `defineDefaultProperties()` for the additional changes in `form()` to take effect.